# Placing A TextView in the centre of ImageView inside TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android, and I would like to Place A TextView in the centre of a ImageView inside a TableRow. The textView are separated with the image view, how can i place the textView inside on top of the imageView? And because it's inside the tableRow I can't use layout_alignLeft or layout_alignRight to centre the .

Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Something like:

```
<TableRow>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/durationView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blk_duration"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/durationTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/duration"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_duration" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/durationView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blk_duration"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/durationTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/duration"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_duration" />

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following layout:

```
<TableRow>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/durationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:src="@drawable/blk_duration" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/durationTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/duration"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_duration" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="odp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/durationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:src="@drawable/blk_duration" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/durationTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/duration"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_duration" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an relativelayout inside Tablerow. Then inside relativelayout place imageview and textview. Adjust your textview accordingly by draging in ui to the place where ever you need to put. Hope I Answer your question.

Comment: I have tried to place a relative layout inside the TableRow, but the width is wider than the screen.

Comment: use the layout width of relative layout matchparent